# ADO Query to Show Parent Child Along with Orphan UserStories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

In my Azure DevOps project, I am using Feature and User Story. Some of the User Stories (Child) are linked to Feature (Parent). But some User Story have no parent. I want a query which will give me the Parent -> Child Grouping, but if a User Story is not linked to any Feature then display them too at the parent level.

Below is my query design I have tried that gives me Parent -> Child Linking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you could get close to what you are asking for would be to have your top level pull both Feature and User Story.  Then you would have it just always "Return all top level items."  You end up duplicating the user stories though.

[image]

Two possible alternatives:

You could inverse it so only User Story is the top level and you show the parents instead of children.

[image]

Alternatively, "Parent" isn't a field you can query, but you can show it on the column listing.

[image]